# Why do I see a vertical scrollbar in Firefox (81.0.1), but not in Chrome (78.0.3904.108), Edge, Safari, Qtweb?

Tags: html, css, firefox, iframe

Consider the following css, html:

```css
header, nav { display: block; }                                     /* IE<9 */
html, body, #main, iframe { height: 100%; }                         /* iframe height: 100% of containing divs */
body,iframe { margin: 0; border: 0; }                               /* seamless */
iframe      { display: block;                                       /* avoid extra pixels/scrollbar in old style flexbox model (Safari, QtWeb) */
              width: 100%; }                                        /* width: IE, Edge */

#main       { 
              display: -webkit-box; -webkit-box-orient: block-axis; /* old style flexbox model, in vertical direction */
              display: -webkit-flex; -webkit-flex-direction:column; /* flexbox Apple */
              display: -ms-flexbox; -ms-flex-direction: column;     /* flexbox IE 10 */
              display: flex; flex-flow: column; }                   /* flexbox, direction */
              
iframe      { -webkit-box-flex: 1;                                  /* flex item old style, prevent appearance y-scrollbar */
              flex: 0 1 auto; }                                     /* Chrome , Qtweb */    
 
header      {background-color: lightgrey;}  
nav         {background-color: grey;}
iframe      {background-color: red;}
footer      {background-color: grey;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Why do I see a vertical scrollbar in Firefox (81.0.1), but not in Chrome (78.0.3904.108), Edge, Safari, Qtweb</title> 


</head>
<body>
<div id="main" role="main">
    <header>
        <h1>Test iframe height (Windows 10)</h1>
        <h2>No y-scrollbar is expected</h2>
    </header>
    <nav><a>Menu here</a></nav>
    <iframe name="content" src="https://example.com/"> </iframe>
    <footer><h1>Footer here</h1></footer>
</div>
</body></html>
```

In Chrome and any other browser I tested on Windows 10, the content of the iframe is shrunk in order to fit the surrounding div. But in the newer versions of Firefox this behaviour has changed.
How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

> flex: 0 1 auto

by

> flex: 1 0 0

This will start the iframe with zero height and then extend.